# What are the use cases for symfony2's ACL system?

Tags: php, performance, symfony, acl

In the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) they mention as an example that we can restrict access to a *comment*.

But if I didn't get it wrong, the system would be storing a different ACE for each *instance*. So I guess there would be at least one extra row somewhere in the db for each comment.

Is this suitable for high-traffic sites ? Could this create a bottleneck ?

How do sites like stackoverflow or wikipedia manage their ACL's?(I might have to create another post for this question)

PS: Please don't bring the 'premature optimization' thing, I prefer to make this kind of things right by design. Gradual optimization can always be done in other places.